# Python3 - imaplib - decrypt using pem certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pem, imaplib

As part of a larger workflow, I've been supplied with an email and password, and with an .pfx-certificate and password for that certificate. I need to use those to download a specific e-mail (specifically, its attachment), so it can be processed in other scripts.

I've already managed to transform the .pfx-file into a .pem file. Using the code below, I can download the message:

```
import email
import imaplib

EMAIL = 'test@test.com'
PASSWORD = 'testpassword'
SERVER = "outlook.office365.com"

# Connect to the server and go to its inbox
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SERVER, port=993)
mail.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
mail.select('inbox')

# Get the relevant mail ID
status, ids = mail.search(None, '(HEADER Subject "Testmessage_")')
mail_id = ids[0].split()[0]

# Fetch the mail, get the data, write the file
status, contents = mail.fetch(mail_id, '(RFC822)')
data = contents[0][1]
with open("outputfile.txt", "wb") as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(data)
```

I can then decode outputfile.txt with OpenSSL with the following command:

```
openssl cms -decrypt -in outputfile.txt -inkey cert.pem > outputmessage.txt
```

I can confirm that in the outputmessage.txt-file, the contents of the attachment are visible, and with some workaround, usable in the rest of my Python-script.

However, this means working with multiple temporary files and (at least) three different commands (python - openssl - python again). I would like to do all of this in Python, so I don't have to create temporary files and can process the results right away in the following scripts.
Additionally, I'd prefer to use as few external dependencies as possible.

I've seen M2Crypto and cryptography mentioned, but I can't seem to get either package working on my machine (something with wheels?). Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Trivially,

```py
import subprocess

# ...

subprocess.run(['openssl', 'cms', '-decrypt',
        '-inkey', 'cert.pem', '-out', 'outputmessage.txt'],
    input=data, check=True)
```

I don't have `openssl cms` locally but I'm guessing from the man page that it will read standard input if you don't pass in an `-in` option.  If that's not true, maybe try something like `-in`, `-` or maybe replace `-` with `/dev/stdin` or whatever your platform offers.